# How can I add shapekey to keyframe in timeline in 2.8?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

recently I've added some shapekeys to one of my objects and I want to make some animation out of this. Yet, I can't find any possibilities to apply this to timeline. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean keyframe(keyshape)?

Comment: I mean adding keyframes to timeline, so I can make animation out of my shapekeys. Propably I should switch keyshape to shapekey so it won't confuse.

Comment: You just want to change shapes in animation, right?

Comment: @yash Yes, using keyshapes I created before and applying them to timeline.

Comment: You are really terrifying me using the word "keyshape" :/

Comment: haha I meant shapekey. Sorry it's too similar to keyframe and it's confuses me. About my question, can you tell me how to apply shapekey to timeline animation? :)

Comment: You have created shapekeys and can't handle them in timeline?

Comment: Yes, I can't find any shapekeys in timeline.

Comment: Okay let me confirm the method, then I will tell you

Comment: I found solution. In order to apply shape key to timeline you have to press "I" over the value and than animate.

Comment: Thats the spirit!